# C++11 : map::lower_bound doesn't work correctly for 2 or less elements in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++11, debian

If I run following C++11 example in Linux (Debian 7, GCC 4.8.2, Eclipse CDT), the while cycle is infinite. First loop is correct. Iterator is decremented by 1 and it references to the first map element. But second and other loops are incorrect. Decrement operator doesn't decrement iterator. It still references to the first element. 
If I remove comment (in map initialization), while cycle will stop.
Could you please tell me, what I did wrong? 
Thank you very much for every comment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::map<int, int> mymap = {{1, 100}, {2, 200}/*, {3, 300}*/};
    auto it = mymap.lower_bound(2);
    cout << "mymap key: " << it->first << endl;
    while(--it != buff.end())
        cout << "mymap key: " << it->first << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note: This code works correct under Windows platform (Visual studio 2013 Express).

Comment: --begin() is undefined behaviour.

Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417171/stl-iterator-before-stdmapbegin

Comment: why are you trying to reach the end() of the map decrementing the iterator in the while loop? Misterious things you will find in that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass a `begin()` iterator to this line:

```
while(--it != buff.end())
```

And `--begin()` yields undefined behaviour.