# How do I get the previous element of a list using the same iterator?

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, c++11, visual-c++

I am making a Sudoku solver and I cannot manage to get backtracking working by refering to the last element of my list (which holds the positions of the blank spaces).

The code below shows my naive initial approach to this issue:

```
void solve(int arr[9][9])
{
    position CurrentPos;

    list<position>::iterator j;
    for (j = blankSpaces.begin();  j != blankSpaces.end();  j++)
    {
        CurrentPos.row = j->row;
        CurrentPos.col = j->col;

        for (int i = arr[CurrentPos.row][CurrentPos.col] + 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (valid(arr, CurrentPos, i))
            {
                arr[CurrentPos.row][CurrentPos.col] = i;
                visitedStack.emplace_front(CurrentPos);
            }
            if (!(valid(arr, CurrentPos, i)) && (i == 9))
            {
                j--;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `auto last = std::prev(std::end(my_list))`?

Comment: should that be used instead of `j--`

Comment: instead of what?

Comment: sorry thought we could use multiple lines

Comment: `CurrentPos` could be renamed as `currentPos`... just some coding standards :P

Comment: oh yeah camelCase

Comment: Prefer `std::vector` for problems like Sudoku solver.  A `std::list` is not  "iteration" friendly

Comment: @jkengineeringworkvideos I wrote an answer. Please check it out and accept if it answers your question, or comment if you want an explanation.

Comment: noob question.... can vector handle a dynamic number of structures?

Comment: yes, ofc. you can add dynamic number of structures

Comment: You absolutely have to create and provide a [mcve] as part of your question. Your problem is not that you can't decrement an iterator and this (required!) process would have shown you that. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) can solve your problem instead of `std::List`. >The storage of the vector is handled automatically, being expanded and contracted as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the last element of the list by doing the following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>

int main () {
    std::list<int> mylist;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        mylist.push_back (i*10);

    auto last = std::prev(mylist.end());
    std::cout << "The last element is " << *last << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Or you can get the iterator before another iterator by using the same like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>

int main () {
    std::list<int> mylist;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        mylist.push_back (i*10);

    auto last = std::prev(mylist.end());
    auto prelast = std::prev(last);
    std::cout << "The last element is " << *last << '\n';
    std::cout << "The prelast element is " << *prelast << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Or just use `--` as you already do:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>

int main () {
    std::list<int> mylist;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        mylist.push_back (i*10);

    auto last = std::prev(mylist.end());
    auto prelast = std::prev(last);
    std::cout << "The last element is " << *last << '\n';
    std::cout << "The prelast element is " << *prelast << '\n';

    prelast--;
    std::cout << "The preprelast element is " << *prelast << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Visual studio said that we can't decrement a iterator

Comment: Also I wanna avoid another iterator

Comment: _Visual studio said that we can decrement a iterator_ - can or cannot? If you want to avoid another iterator just reassign like this `auto it = std::prev(mylist.end()); it = std::prev(it);` That will give you the prelast iterator

Comment: it said we can't decrement a begin list iterator

Comment: of course you can't when decrementing a begin list iterator is undefined behavior. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417171/stl-iterator-before-stdmapbegin)

Comment: @jkengineeringworkvideos so basically you need to make sure you don't need to decrement first iterator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206774/discussion-between-jk-engineering-work-videos-and-nutcracker).